# Django( version 2.1.1) Admin panel change after upgrade to Django( version 3.2)

Tags: python, django, django-admin, ubuntu-18.04, django-3.2

**What did I do?**

I have upgrade Django(version 2.1.1) from Django(version 3.2) on Ubuntu 18.04 server

**What did I expect to happen?**

I was expecting the same admin panel but got a different admin panel. As you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HyeM.png)
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1048-aws x86_64)

Python: Python 3.6.9 (default, Jan 26 2021, 15:33:00)

Comment: Thanks for editing  @Çağatay Barın

Comment: Can you explain the problem clearly? It's normal of packages to change things over updates, that's why you should be careful when you update packages and at least take a look at the change logs between versions

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın As due to upgraded Django, I get admin panel is not as same as shown in Django2.1.1. Now I had resolved this problem  by using admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False in admin.py file and admin.site.unregister(TokenProxy) so my token can't show on admin panel.